# Generated apk is unsigned after gradle plugin update

Tags: android, gradle, apk, jar-signing

So, my project was doing fine until I updated android gradle plugin to version 3.6. Now, when I generate release apk via "Generate signed APK" in Android Studio, or build a release apk on our CI, it generates an apk that is unsigned.
I use jre's "jarsigner" tool to verify it (jarsigner --verify --certs D:\app-release.apk) and it tells me that "jar is unsigned".
I have a signing config in my build.gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file(signing.keyPathRetail)
        storePassword signing.storePasswordRetail
        keyAlias signing.keyAliasRetail
        keyPassword signing.keyPasswordRetail
    }
}
```

The keystore's location and all passwords are correct. The keystore itself wasn't changed in years. The same exact project is generating a valid signed apk when I revert the com.android.tools.build:gradle dependency back to version 3.4.2.

I've found out that if I open the generated apk in 7-zip, it is missing files "CERT.RSA" and "CERT.SF" in the META-INF folder (the apk generated with 3.4.2 gradle plugin version has them), but I don't have any idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Just straightaway go :
Build - Generate Signed APK - Select the keystore and key, and you are on your way.

It worked for me.

Try following the steps:-

In Android Studio goto File > Project Structure and untick from "use embedded JDK" then click OK

Goto Computer Settings (system settings) (win + pause key) then go to Advanced system settings>Environment variables. if JAVA_HOME not present then add it and set path to your installed JDK.
If you can't find a direct approach to modify JDK path, do the  following(for the last step) BUT MAKE SURE YOU MAKE BACKUP BEFORE THIS.

To make sure where you are guiding come to project view,  delete".grade", ".idea", "capture", "gradle" folders from the root and "build", "release", "lib" folder from "app" leaving "src" as it is. Delete root.iml and don't delete app.iml file Then rebuild the project and then create the Signed package

Comment: I tried that, the apk is still unsigned with the new version of the plugin

Comment: Try creating a new keystore.

Comment: But if I create a new keystore, wouldn't clients on older versions be unable to update without uninstalling the app?

Comment: So you have the app released ? Ok.

Comment: Tried the edited answer, still unsigned. I don't think that the problem is with my local project, because it also happens when apk is built on Jenkins, and on other people's computers, including Mac and Linux.

Comment: Well. Then, is your jarsigner tool of the correct version ? Because, sometimes, an incorrect version causes any error. I.e. the APK is signed but it shows that as unsigned.

Comment: Well, even if jarsigner is incorrect, I can't install this apk over older signed version, AND the apk is missing cert files in the META-INF folder, so there's definitely something wrong with it.